# Does countDistinct doesnt work anymore in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Getting the following error when using `countDistinct` function. The error is only with this particular function and other works fine.

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/02/11 00:05:02 WARN SparkConf: Note that spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone/kubernetes and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "script.py", line 74, in <module>
    df = df.groupby(['InstanceKey1','PeriodStartTime','TetheringIndication']).agg(psf.countDistinct('ClientIP'),psf.sum('OctetsIn'),psf.sum('OctetsOut'))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 991, in countDistinct
    return count_distinct(col, *cols)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1008, in count_distinct
    jc = sc._jvm.functions.count_distinct(_to_java_column(col), _to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1531, in __getattr__
    "{0}.{1} does not exist in the JVM".format(self._fqn, name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count_distinct does not exist in the JVM
```

Comment: there is a probleme in your code. You say that the fucntion `countDistinct` creates the error, but the log message says `count_distinct` which is not the same function.

Comment: A code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: It’s for both countDistinct and count_distinct